# Arraylist print trim or split string

Tags: java, arraylist

I have fetch data from database and put result-set in Array-list.
I need to Print each String from Array-list can split or trim to string. 
Ouput for below code and Expect result.

```
public static ArrayList<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>();   
public ArrayList<Object> databaseconection(WebDriver driver, String sqlquery)
        throws InterruptedException, SQLException {

    Statement stmt = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new SybDriver());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    String url = "***************";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "451552", "Welcome"     conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    // Database query to get value
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlquery);

    while (rs.next()) {
        for (int i = 1; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount() + 1; i++) {
            // System.out.print(" " + rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) + "=" +
            // rs.getObject(i));
            // System.out.println("");
            myList.add(rs.getObject(i));
        }
        System.out.println(myList);
        //  round off to nearest million
        for (int i = 1; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount() + 1; i++) {
            Object object2 = rs.getObject(i);
            object2 = ((BigDecimal) object2).divide(new BigDecimal("1000000")).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)
                    + "";
            System.out.println(object2);

            // Print each Array from my list
            Add_Log.info(myList.toString() + " round off to nearest million = " + object2);
            Reporter.log(myList.toString() + " round off to nearest million = " + object2);
        }
    }
    return myList;

}
```

Console result for above code.

```
[1995537811893.93004, 1131932531051.9879252, 1174448486100.98669, 39942430884.26804, 2224235008605.54787, 2940469028187.27436]
1995538
INFO [main] (BaselPage.java:114) - [1995537811893.93004, 1131932531051.9879252, 1174448486100.98669, 39942430884.26804, 2224235008605.54787, 2940469028187.27436] round off to nearest million =1995538
1131933
INFO [main] (BaselPage.java:114) - [1995537811893.93004, 1131932531051.9879252, 1174448486100.98669, 39942430884.26804, 2224235008605.54787, 2940469028187.27436] round off to nearest million =1131933
1174448
INFO [main] (BaselPage.java:114) - [1995537811893.93004, 1131932531051.9879252, 1174448486100.98669, 39942430884.26804, 2224235008605.54787, 2940469028187.27436] round off to nearest million =1174448
39942
INFO [main] (BaselPage.java:114) - [1995537811893.93004, 1131932531051.9879252, 1174448486100.98669, 39942430884.26804, 2224235008605.54787, 2940469028187.27436] round off to nearest million =39942
2224235
INFO [main] (BaselPage.java:114) - [1995537811893.93004, 1131932531051.9879252, 1174448486100.98669, 39942430884.26804, 2224235008605.54787, 2940469028187.27436] round off to nearest million =2224235
2940469
INFO [main] (BaselPage.java:114) - [1995537811893.93004, 1131932531051.9879252, 1174448486100.98669, 39942430884.26804, 2224235008605.54787, 2940469028187.27436] round off to nearest million =2940469
```

I Expect output  each line

```
 [1995537811893.93004, 1131932531051.9879252, 1174448486100.98669, 39942430884.26804, 2224235008605.54787, 2940469028187.27436] mylist Arraylist
  ///// Each line 
[1995537811893.93004] round off to nearest million =1995538
[1131932531051.9879252] round off to nearest million = 1131933
[1174448486100.98669] round off to nearest million = 1174448
[39942430884.26804] round off to nearest million = 39942
[2224235008605.54787] round off to nearest million = 2224235
[2940469028187.27436] round off to nearest million = 2940469
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the entire list to string each time. Use mylist.get(i) instead (you don't need toString() here).

Comment: it's an ArrayList, he can't access it like you said, he needs to use the .get() method

Comment: @vc73 yes I cant use get method any other way

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlquery);

        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount() + 1; i++) {
                // System.out.print(" " + rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) + "=" +
                // rs.getObject(i));
                // System.out.println("");
                myList.add(rs.getObject(i));
            }
            System.out.println(myList);
            //  round off to nearest million

                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < myList.size(); i1++) {
                // Print each Array from my list
                    myListdec = myList.get(i1);
                Add_Log.info(myList.get(i1) + " round off to nearest million = " +  ((BigDecimal) myListdec).divide(new BigDecimal("1000000")).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)+ "");
                Reporter.log(myList.get(i1) + " round off to nearest million = " +  ((BigDecimal) myListdec).divide(new BigDecimal("1000000")).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)+ "");

                }
```